# Using database resources in Axiom Safe Request

Tags: java, axiom

I would like to know how to make use of an Axiom database resource inside a Safe function.

Right now I'm just handling the connection manually but I know it would be better to use the already defined resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how.

if ever need to do it, you can do it like this:

define db resource in safe.t_resources and then in the safe function java code:

`String DB_RESOURCE="DATABASE";
 this.dbResource = getResource(this.DB_RESOURCE);
 Oracle oracle = new Oracle(this.dbResource);
 Connection conn = oracle.getConnection();`

yep, that simple